# Why does my Apple Watch repeatedly say, "Trust This Computer?"

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, apple-watch

I have a first generation Apple Watch and an iPhone 7Plus. For the most part everything works fine. However, I get the following notice on my Apple watch every few weeks:

> Trust This Computer? Your settings and data will be accessible from this computer when connected.

It does not say which computer is to be trusted. Is it my iPhone, or my MacBook Pro?

It seems that once a watch and phone are paired that the trust relationship is established and there shouldn't be any additional trust requests.

Why does this happen repeatedly and is there anything I can do to resolve it completely?

Comment: Do you have the macOS Console app open when you have this notice pop up?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I do have Xcode open a lot though. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Good news is that it’s Xcode talking to your Apple Watch so you can view logs and debug and stuff. Bad news is that I don’t know why this happens repeatedly. Likely a bug. You could try opening Xcode, then going to Apple Watch app > Settings > General > Profiles and seeing if anything shows up there that you can set your Apple Watch to trust. If this helps out, let me know and I’ll make it an answer.

Comment: I don't see anything that resembles that. I'll check all my devices next time the notice pops up. Thanks.